# Failed to execute 'createPolicy' on 'TrustedTypePolicyFactory': Policy "goog#html" disallowed

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

If I run the GoogleTagManager with CSP I get the following error

> Failed to execute 'createPolicy' on 'TrustedTypePolicyFactory': Policy
> "goog#html" disallowed.

My header script looks like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXX&amp;l=dataLayer&amp;cx=c"></script>
<script id="GTMscript" data-cookieconsent="ignore" async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXX"></script>
   <script id="Cookiebot" src="https://consent.cookiebot.com/uc.js" data-cbid="XXXX" data-blockingmode="auto" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <meta http-equiv='Content-Security-Policy'
                      content="
                      default-src 'self';
                      frame-src 'self' https://consentcdn.cookiebot.com;
                      img-src 'self'https://storage.googleapis.com ;
                      font-src 'self';
                      base-uri 'none'; 
                      connect-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com ;
                      script-src 'self'https://consent.cookiebot.com https://consentcdn.cookiebot.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic';
                      style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
                      trusted-types angular angular#unsafe-bypass;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just beginning to implement TrustedTypes and found this question when checking for Google's compatibility with TrustedTypes.

Have you tried updating `trusted-types angular angular#unsafe-bypass;` with `trusted-types angular angular#unsafe-bypass goog#html;`?